# How to animate uitext label when there is a change in text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to animate a text label when there is a change in it.
For ex, I got a price label which will be changed(dropped) regarding to the time.
If price is 100.25 and dropped to 100.24, I want to animate last digit.

Is there a good animation library for the purpose I mention?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You can use Fade effect

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
animation.duration = 0.75;
[aLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"kCATransitionFade"];

// This will fade:
aLabel.text = xxx
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It will animate all the label not a single digit that he said.

Comment: yea definitely, need to animate only the digit

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try This One Hope So Helpful
```

- (void)animateLabelShowText:(NSString*)newText characterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
  {
  [self.myLabel setText:@""];

  for (int i=0; i

  ```
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];
  ```

  }
  }

Comment: there is not a method like this in objective-c